# Kal iPhone Calendar - UITableView doesn't work

Tags: iphone, calendar

I was just trying to use the Kal Calendar. For now the dots under the days work, but when I tap one of the dates it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer on this forum if you are more specific: What is "Kal Calendar"?  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What are you doing now (hint: post some code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kal Calendar is pretty easy to use. Just follow the instructions from githib.
Herew is the link.
https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Also, two examples are given which thoruougly explain the usage of Kal calendar. 
Native Cal exaplins how to sync the calendar with iphone inbuilt calendar
And, Holidays explain how to sync the calendar with your customized datasource. It has given 2 database: sqlite and JSOn. Both work great.

But in my project I was working with core data, so I just replaced sqlite code in SQLDataSource with  my core data code and it worked like a charm!!

Thanks You Kal!!